# Modifying an object stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, dictionary

I'm attempting to simulate Langton's ant using Zelle's graphics.py (I can't change libraries because this is for a specific class) and I'm stuck!

I've created a grid of squares, each a unique object, so that I can modify the color of an individual square depending on which square the ant object is "touching" (occupying the same coordinates). For each movement of the ant, I want to detect the fill (i.e. "white", "black") of which grid piece shares the same coordinates, so that I can change the color of that square and move the ant accordingly. I created the grid of squares and stored each square into a dictionary like this:

```
def drawgrid():
"""draws a grid of white squares, each individual objects instead of
intersecting lines so that the position of each square can be determined and
the color of each square can be individually changed"""
square = Rectangle(Point(0,0), Point(1,1))
square.setFill("white")
coordinate_dict={}
for x in range (0, 51):
    for y in range (0, 51):
        newsquare = square.clone()
        newsquare.move(x, y)
        newsquare.draw(win)
        coordinate_dict[str(x+.5) + "," + str(y+.5)] = newsquare #offset to match center coordinates
return coordinate_dict
```

and i'm using the coordinate_dict in my moveant() function here:

```
def moveant(ant):
"""
moves the ant according to rules of langton's ant
detects the coordinate of the square below the ant
changes the ant's position
and changes the color of the lower block
"""

ant.draw(win)
coordinate_dict = drawgrid()

rules = [("white", "up", "right", "black"),
         ("white", "down", "left", "black"),
         ("white", "right", "down", "black"),
         ("white", "left", "up", "black"),
         ("black", "up", "left", "white"),
         ("black", "down", "right", "white"),
         ("black", "left", "down", "white"),
         ("black", "right", "up", "white")]


for (color, direction, new_direction, new_color) in rules:
    for key in coordinate_dict:
        current_location = ant.getLocation()
        xcoord = str(current_location.getX())
        #print xcoord
        ycoord = str(current_location.getY())
        #print ycoord
        current_direction = ant.getDirection()

        if ((xcoord + "," + ycoord) == key) and \
        (key.getConfig("fill") == color) and \
        (current_direction == direction):
          # print "hello"
           ant._move(new_direction)
          # print new_direction
           key.setFill(new_color)
          # print new_color
```

however, I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "langton.py", line 156, in <module>
main()
File "langton.py", line 133, in main
moveant(langton)
File "langton.py", line 120, in moveant
(key.getConfig("fill") == color) and \
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getConfig'
```

from what I understand, the way I've written this loop has the program attempting to use .getConfig() on the key rather than the square object stored under the key. However, I'm not sure how to access the square object so that I can use its "fill" value in my if statement. any help is appreciated!

Comment: ```for key, value in coordinate_dict.iteritems(): value.getConfig("fill")```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of just `key` use `coordinate_dict[key]`.